# JSon array dynamic column filling AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an Object like this:

```
var myObject= [
{"name":'Tom', "city":'Chicago',"GroupCode":'1'}, 
{"name":'Harry', "city":'Wisconsin',"GroupCode":'1'}, 
{"name":'Rob', "city":'Los Angeles',"GroupCode":'2'}, 
{"name":'Peter', "city":'Seattle',"GroupCode":'2'}, 
{"name":'Dave', "city":'New York',"GroupCode":'3'}, 
{"name":'Steve', "city":'Boston',"GroupCode":'3}
];
```

transforming as

```
var myObject= [
    {"name":'Tom', "city":'Chicago',"GroupCode":'1'}, 
    {"name":'Harry', "city":'Wisconsin',"GroupCode":'1'}, 
    {"name":'--', "city":'--',"GroupCode":'--'}, 
    {"name":'Rob', "city":'Los Angeles',"GroupCode":'2'}, 
    {"name":'Peter', "city":'Seattle',"GroupCode":'2'}, 
    {"name":'--', "city":'--',"GroupCode":'--'}, 
    {"name":'Dave', "city":'New York',"GroupCode":'3'}, 
    {"name":'Steve', "city":'Boston',"GroupCode":'3} 
    ];
```

using the following code to add new records in between when ever GroupCode is changing:

```
var gc = myObject[0].GroupCode;
myObject.forEach(function(ob, index) {
  if (gc != ob.GroupCode) {
    gc = ob.GroupCode;
    //insert this object
    myObject.splice(index, 0, {
      "name": '--',
      "city": '--',
      "GroupCode": '--'
    });
  }
})
```

How can i make the keys/columns dynamic here ?

```
myObject.splice(index, 0, {
          "name": '--',
          "city": '--',
          "GroupCode": '--'
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
myObject.forEach(function(ob, index) {
  if (gc != ob.GroupCode) {
    gc = ob.GroupCode;
    keys = Object.keys(ob);
    var a = {};
    //dynamically creating keys in object
    a[keys[0]] = '--'
    a[keys[1]] = '--'
    a[keys[2]] = '--'
    //insert this object
    myObject.splice(index, 0, a);
  }

})
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/teggj208/)

Or you can do it like this too making it more dynamic.

```
myObject.forEach(function(ob, index) {
  if (gc != ob.GroupCode) {
    gc = ob.GroupCode;
    keys = Object.keys(ob);
    var a = {};
    //iterate over  keys and make object
    keys.forEach(function(key){
      a[key] = '--'
      a[key] = '--'
      a[key] = '--'
    })
    //insert this object
    myObject.splice(index, 0, a);
  }

})
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/Lk0cunot/)

Comment: Thank you Cyril, That helped me.